# Finding the zeros of a complex function on a disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have encountered the following problem:

> Find the number of zeros of $f(x)$ on the disk $|z|$ < $1/2$ where
>   $f(x)$ = $z^2$+$cosh(iz)$

How would one compute the solution?

Comment: Rouché's theorem. It may help to note that $\cosh (iz) = \cos z$.

Comment: the identity helps a lot!!  I think I need to use the power series representation of cos z and then use the argument principle?

Comment: The power series isn't so useful here. Use the addition theorems to find $\lvert \cos z\rvert^2$ and get an estimate to use in Rouché's theorem.

Comment: what are the addition theorems? also why $|cos z|^2$ ?

Comment: $\cos (a+b) = \dotsc$ is the addition theorem you need here. Ultimately, you need $\lvert \cos z\rvert$ of course, but I hope that computing $\lvert \cos z\rvert^2$ makes it easier to see the useful form to get the required estimate.

Answer (score 1):

For $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| < \frac12$, write $z$ as $x + iy$ where
$x,y \in (-\frac12,\frac12)$. We have

$$\begin{align}
& \cosh(iz) = \cosh(-y+ix) = \cosh(y)\cos(x) - \sinh(y)\sin(x) i\\
\implies & \Re \cosh(iz) = \cosh(y)\cos(x) \ge \cos\left(\frac12\right)\\
\implies & \Re( z^2 + \cosh(iz) ) \ge \cos\left(\frac12\right) - \frac14
\approx 0.6275825618903728 > 0
\end{align}
$$
As a result $z^2 + \cosh(iz) \ne 0$ for $|z| < \frac12$.

Comment: does your $\Re$ denote residue, or real component?

Comment: @user3677952 $\Re$ here stands for the real part. it is not my preferred choice of how to specify the real part but it is the standard on math.SE.